# Are higher-end multivitamins harmful/helpful/placebo?

Tags: vitamins

For instance, consider multivitamins like Opti-Men or Orange Triads or AOR Ortho-Core, etc.

Are such multivitamin supplements actually beneficial to health, or is it a waste/possibly even harmful?

Comment: Pure nutrition questions are off topic according to the [FAQ]. Anyway, consider eating an apple instead of a magic pill.

Comment: I am not asking about multivitamins as a replacement. I am asking about multivitamins as a supplement to healthy diet/exercise. With a decent diet + exercise, are pricier multivitamins worth it or not, and why?

Comment: Please check the [FAQ] your question has no exercise relation and thus is off topic.

Comment: This question is off-topic per the [FAQ](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq) and will be closed. Only nutrition questions related to fitness are on-topic. We welcome you to rephrase your question in such a way that it has a direct tie-in to fitness and we can re-open the question.